# Auto insert text at end of line of a rich text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, richtextarea, inputrichtext

Here is the requirement:

I have a Visualforce page with inputfield which is a rich text field. I want to insert a timestamp value where ever the cursor is present. I have a code that runs perfectly on a html textarea [jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/et9borp4/] but I am not able to make it work on Salesforce's inputField.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
   $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.insert-timestamp-btn').click(function(){
            var tstamp = new Date();
            insertAtCursor($j('#notes'),formatDate(tstamp));
        });
   });

      function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
            //IE support
            if (document.selection) {
                myField.focus();
                sel = document.selection.createRange();
                sel.text = myValue;
            }
            // Microsoft Edge
            else if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
              var startPos = myField.selectionStart; 
              var endPos = myField.selectionEnd; 

              myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue 
                     + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length); 

              var pos = startPos + myValue.length;
              myField.focus();
              myField.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
            }
            //MOZILLA and others
            else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
                var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
                var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
                myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos)
                    + myValue
                    + myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
            } else {
                myField.value += myValue;
            }
        }

        function formatDate(date) {
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = date.getMinutes();
            var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
            hours = hours % 12;
            hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
            var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
            return date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
        }

</script>

<apex:form id="form">
     //Notes__c is rich text field in Salesforce
    <apex:inputField id="notes" styleClass="notesClass" value="{!cnotes.Notes__c}"/>
    <button type="button" class="insert-timestamp-btn">Insert Timestamp</button>
</apex:form>
```

When I insepcted the notes inputfield, it seems that it is a html body with editable divs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `<apex:... id="...">` component, the `id` value gets prefixed. The simplest fix is to use the "ends with" (`$=`) selector:

```
var input = $("[id$='notes']");
var notFound = $("#notes"); // this value is not the literal id
```

See also:

- [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)
- [Using $Component to Reference Components from JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm?search_text=id)
- [$Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm?search_text=$component)

Comment: So I need to send my inputField element to the insertAtCursor function where it will strip the value and put timestamp at the end. It seems that with rich text in salesforce, there is no val() but text() since it is an html type document.